# Probably simple jQuery selector question

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have some code right now that executes when a link is clicked.  The HTML is structured:

```
<a href='link1'>Stuff<span class='color-bar'></span></a>
<a href='link2'>Stuff<span class='color-bar'></span></a>
<a href='link3'>Stuff<span class='color-bar'></span></a>
```

With the jQuery like so:

```
$('a').liveQuery('click',function(event){
  ...
  ...
  $( selector ).animate({bottom:10},'slow');
}
```

My question is how do I target the specific '.color-bar' using $this?  Before I had each one assigned an id, but then realized it was overkill and figured I could do it using the $this element.

I tried `$( $this > '.color-bar' )` but that didn't work.  Am I just getting syntax wrong or approaching it incorrectly?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an a tag with a class of .color-bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### solution

```
$('.color-bar', $this)
```

or

```
$(this).find('.color-bar')
```

#### note

`.find()` is a bit faster than the first solution, because the first solution calls find anyway internally in jQuery. But it looks a bit more nice

Comment: For what it's worth, I tend to use the second form - my mind finds it easier to understand, and thus more maintainable, which always wins with similar/same results solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('.color-bar').animate({bottom:10},'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children('.color-bar').animate({bottom:10},'slow');
```